# Mysql count month

Tags: mysql

I have a list of dates from table like this:
2014-05-21
2014-08-20
2014-06-03
2014-06-03
2014-05-24
2014-05-28
2014-05-24
2014-05-27
2014-08-20
2014-05-28
and so on.

I need to count the total grouped by month for each date like this: 05 = 6, 06 = 2, 08 = 2.

I am very noob in mysql, can you guys help me on how I should do this? Thanks.

Comment: Does it matter that they might not all be the same year?

Comment: Yes I just noticed that :| I may just have to include WHERE `YEAR(date)` = 2014 in the query. Wait, that is wrong I guess.

Comment: You could, but that cannot use an index. Better to say " date between '2014-01-01' and '2014-12-31' "

Answer (score 2):

You can do so

```
select month(`date`) `month`,
count(*)
from test 
group by `month`
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3b4d/2)

Comment: Any idea on how do I count if it is not the same year?

Comment: @ShahErhan you can change group by to `group by year(date),month` and for select `month(date) month, year(date)`

Answer (score 1):

In order to count by month and year you should add a year column in your result and add it to group by.

```
   select YEAR(`date`)  `year`,MONTH(`date`) `month`,
   count(*)
   from test 
   GROUP BY YEAR(`date`), MONTH(`date`) DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this query it would work, may be with some alteration

```
 "select count(DATE_FORMAT(date_column, '%m')) form your_table group by date_coloumn"
```

or

```
 "select count(*),DATE_FORMAT(date_column, '%m') form your_table group by date_coloumn"
```

Comment: I've tried your solution with some alteration but I can't get it right. The other answer works flawlessly. Thanks by the way.

Comment: i have a mistake in form instead of form, any ways purpose is achieved and thats great (Y)